# Using segment for ReferralID in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, get

As you know CodeIgniter can easily destroy `_GET`,

The only thing i needed this for is ReferralID (inviter id), such as `site.com/?refuser=USERNAME`

But i can also get it by segment like: `site.com/refuser/USERNAME`

Is there any downside to this segment method? for example in Google searchs etc? also i was thinking some one might create a user called HACKED then simply use `site.com/refuser/HACKED`

1. Can i just disallow search engines for this /refuser/ and the issue i mentioned will be fixed?
2. Does this method have any downside i am not aware of?
3. What do you suggest? any better idea?

Comment: You can build google friendly URLs with [routes](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html). You should also implement server side controls on that parameter to avoid unwanted behaviours.

Comment: Thank you, my URLs are already Google friendly, the question was for ReferralID , i was asking if using segments instead of GET method is okay to get the REFRRAL ID

Comment: Yes it is, both methods are pretty much the same thing